# How to write a simple function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do you create a function in jQuery, call it, and pass a variable to it?  Here it is in Javascript style:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function popup(msg) {
  alert(msg);
}
</script>
```

Then you would simply include the event in the HTML:

```
<html>
<input type="submit" onclick="popup('My Message')" />
</html>
```

What is the jQuery equivalent to doing this?  From all the "newbie" tutorials, they are all static functions that do not accept variables.  For example:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('button').click(function() {
    alert('hello, world');
   });
});
</script>
```

I want to be able to dynamically include different messages.  The code above affects all buttons and spits out the same message of 'hello, world'.

Comment: jQuery is not a language, by the way. Anything you can do in JavaScript won't be broken just by including jQuery.

Comment: What's on server side? ASP.NET, PHP etc...

Comment: @RayCheng Why would that be relevant? ;)

Comment: To expand upon what @minitech said, jQuery *extends* the functionality of JavaScript. jQuery does not have a different way to create a function. Instead, what jQuery offers (among other things) is a better way to call or trigger your JavaScript functions. In your example, JQ gives you an easy way to execute a function when it detects the button click event.

Comment: @Niko, if OP is using ASP.NET Web Form, the common approach would be `alert('<%=GetMessage()%>');`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you want the message to be dynamic, you're going to want to use `data-attributes`:

```
<input class='message-button-' type="submit" data-message="My Message" />
```

Then in a separate javascript file:

```
// equivalent of $(document).ready(function(){...
$(function(){

  // Functionality starts here
  $('.message-button').on('click', function(e){
    alert($(this).data('message'));
  })


});
```

Now the function will execute any time a button with class `.message-button` is clicked, and it will use the custom attribute data-message to display a message.

Hope this helps!  :)

Update:

Note that it's considered best-practice to do javascript unobstrusively.  Some people have mentioned still using the `onclick` attribute like you did in your example, don't do that.  Bind the event like I've shown here using jquery's `.on('click', function(){})` method.

If your click item is an anchor tag `<a>` then you can prevent the href from being followed if you want, by using `e.preventDefault`:

```
$('a').on('click', function(e){
  e.preventDefault()
})
```

Also in case you need to know, the `$('.message-button')` is using css selectors to grab dom elements.  Any valid CSS selector will normally work in there.

**Step-by-step**

First, we need to wrap all of our code in a function provided by jQuery that waits until the document is ready to handle javascript actions and dom manipulation.  The long-form version is `$(document).ready(function(){  /* CODE GOES HERE */ })` but the version I've used is a shortcut `$(function({ /* CODE GOES HERE */ })`:

```
$(function(){
})
```

Next, we need to bind an event to our button.  Since we've given it the class `.message-button`, we can use jQuery to grab that element and bind the 'click' event to it:

```
$(function(){
  // Functionality starts here
  $('.message-button').on('click', function(e){
    // Code here executes when the input button is clicked
  })


});
```

Inside of event handlers `this` is re-bound to point directly to the HTML element that triggered the event.  Wrapping in $() gives us access to jquery methods.  Thus:  $(this) is used very frequently.  jQuery gives us the `.data()` method to access any `data-*` methods on the element and give us the value, which is what the `alert()` is doing.

```
$(function(){
  // Functionality starts here
  $('.message-button').on('click', function(e){
    alert($(this).data('message'));
  })


});
```

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate the in-depth explanation and your solution, although I admit I still do not get it.  I am so used to working with PHP and javascript, that the idea of binding to events and working with it, is completely foreign to me.  I will take a break and re-read your explanation later to see if I start to absorb it.

Answer (score 6):

This is my best way to do this just like javascript:

### ---- Make function by using jQuery like this

> ```
> <script>$(document).ready(function(){
>     popup=function(msg){
>       alert(msg);
>     }});
> </script>
> ```

And you don't need to change the code at the body

> ```
> <html>
> <input type="submit" onclick="popup('My Message')" />
> </html>
> ```

Here is the sample http://jsfiddle.net/PLnF3/

### ---- But wait, If you just need to show an alert message maybe this sample is the best:

> ```
> <html>
> <input type="submit" onclick="alert('My Message')" />
> </html>
> ```

You don't need any javascript or jQuery to do this, just use alert('My Message') on your button. Sample http://jsfiddle.net/PLnF3/1/

### ---- If you want a better appearance using jQuery, you can use jQuery Dialog().

Here the example http://howto.software-mirrors.com/2013/09/how-to-make-jquery-popup-window.html
This is the code:

> ```
> <script>
>     $(document).ready(function() {
>         popup = function(msg) {
>             $("<div>" + msg + "</div>").dialog();
>         }
>     });
> </script>
> ```

And you don't need to change the html code on your body.

> ```
> <html>
> <input type="submit" onclick="popup('My Message')" />
> </html>
> ```

Here the example http://jsfiddle.net/PLnF3/2/

Remember, to be able to use jQuery dialog, you need jquery.js, jquery-ui.js and also jquery.css theme. read more at http://howto.software-mirrors.com/2013/09/how-to-make-jquery-popup-window.html

Answer (score 4):

You'd give each button a different ID, like so:

```
<input type="submit" id="submit-something" onclick="popup('My Message')" />
```

Then:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#submit-something').click(function() {
        alert('My message');
    });
});
```

Also, if the task is very repetitive, you can use another function to create the function:

```
function messageHandler(message) {
    return function() {
        alert(message);
    };
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#submit-something').click(messageHandler('My message'));
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You should store the message in a `data-*` attribute:

```
<button data-message="Hi there!">...</button>
```

```javascript
$('button').click(function() {
    alert($(this).data('message'));
});
```

Comment: Please explain in more detail

Comment: @user785179. You should explain in more detail wwhat exactly you're trying to do..

Answer (score 2):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var message = "foo"; // You might need to move it to the global scope,
                         // denepends on what you want to do with it.
  $('button').click(function() {
    alert(message);
   });
   ...
   ...
   message = "hello world";
});
```

Worth saying sbout:

> How do you create a function in jQuery

There is no such thing, create a function in jQuery.

Comment: The variable, message, is still inside the basic jQuery function.  How do I stick my dynamic messages into it?  I cannot pass any variables into jQuery functions?  Is jQuery only good for effects and animations?

Comment: @user785179. If you explain what exactly you want to do... and you can pass parameters to events.

Answer (score 1):

If you're absolutely required to store the data in the HTML code, the data attributes are a good choice:

```
<button class="alert" data-msg="My Message">Click me</button>
```

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('button.alert').click(function() {
      var msg = $(this).data('msg');  // access HTML attribute data-msg
      alert(msg);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

One solution:to use attributes like parameter.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('button').click(function() {
    alert($(this).attr("message"));
   });
});
</script>
<button message="personal message 1">Botton 1</button>
<button message="personal message 1">Botton 2</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

i've tried some of the suggestions and it works great..

--html button

```
<input type="submit" value="Submit 1" class="message" data-message="Sample Message 1"/>
<input type="submit" value="Submit 2" class="message" data-message="Sample Message 2"/>
```

--jquery on button click

```
$('.message').live('click', function(){
      alert($(this).data('message'));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>POS</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script>


function getUnitPrice(){
        var item = document.getElementById('item').value;
        if(item==0){
            document.getElementById('unitprice').value = "36000.00";
        }
        if(item==1){
            document.getElementById('unitprice').value = "2500.00";
        }
        if(item==2){
            document.getElementById('unitprice').value = '14000.00';
        }
        if(item==3){
            document.getElementById('unitprice').value = '40000.00';
        }
        if (item==" "){
            document.getElementById('unitprice').value = '0';
        }


}

function calcSubtotal(){
    var qty = document.getElementById('quantity').value;
    var price = document.getElementById('unitprice').value;
    if(isNaN(qty)||isNaN(price)){
        alert("Please enter valid values");

    }
    else{
        var subtotal= eval(price) * eval(qty);
        document.getElementById('subtotal').value = subtotal;
    }




}


function calcDiscount(){

    var discRate = document.getElementById('discountRate').value;
    var discAmount = document.getElementById('subtotal').value;

    if(isNaN(discRate)||isNaN(discAmount)){
        alert("Please enter valid discount");
        return;
    }
    if(discRate < 5 || discRate > 20 ){
        alert("Please enter valid discount");
        return;
    }

    var discount = eval(discAmount) * eval(discRate)/100;
    document.getElementById('discountAmount').value = discount;
    document.getElementById('total').value= discAmount - discount;



}

function calcBalance(){

    var cash = document.getElementById('cash').value;
    var total = document.getElementById('total').value;

    if(isNaN(cash)){
        alert("Enter valid amount");
        return;
    }

    var bal = eval(total) - eval(cash);
    document.getElementById('balance').value = bal;



}

</script>

</head>

<body class="container">
    <div class="panel panel-primary" style="margin-top: 10px;">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <p style="font-size: 36px; margin: 0;"><strong>Kumara Super Centre</strong></p>
            <p style="font-size: 16px; margin: 0;">No. 300, Ja-ela Road, Gampaha. Tel: 033-2232526</p>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
        <table class="table table-hover">
            <tr>
                <th class="text-center">Item</th>
                <th class="text-center">Quantity</th>
                <th class="text-center">Unit Price</th>
                <th class="text-center">Amount</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="col-lg-5">
                    <select class="form-control" id="item" required onChange="getUnitPrice()">
                        <option value="">Select one</option>
                        <option value="0">Television</option>
                        <option value="1">FM Radio</option>
                        <option value="2">DVD Player</option>
                        <option value="3">Surround System</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
                <td class="col-lg-2">
                    <input class="form-control" type="number" value="0" id="quantity" name="quantity" required onKeyUp="calcSubtotal()" />
                </td>
                <td class="col-lg-2">
                    <input class="form-control" type="number" value="0" id="unitprice" name="unitprice" readonly />
                </td>
                <td class="col-lg-3">
                    <input class="form-control" type="number" value="0" id="subtotal" name="subtotal" readonly />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <table class="table" style="float: right; width: 600px;">
            <tr style="border:none">
                <td class="text-center col-lg-3"><strong>Discount Rate (%)</strong></td>
                <td class="col-lg-2"><input class="form-control" type="number" value="0" id="discountRate" name="discountRate" onKeyUp="calcDiscount()" /></td>
                <td class="col-lg-3"><input class="form-control" type="number" value="0" id="discountAmount" name="discountAmount" readonly /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr style="border-top:none">
                <td class="text-center"><strong>Total</strong></td>
                <td></td>
                <td><input class="form-control" type="number" value="0" id="total" name="total" readonly /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr style="border:none">
                <td class="text-center"><strong>Cash</strong></td>
                <td></td>
                <td><input class="form-control" type="number" value="0" id="cash" name="cash" onKeyUp="calcBalance()" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr style="border:none">
                <td class="text-center"><strong>Balance</strong></td>
                <td></td>
                <td><input class="form-control" type="number" value="0" id="balance"  name="balance" readonly /></td>
            </tr>
        </table>

        </div>



    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, it is always a good idea to add some explanation to your code.